# commercial certificate for Adobe AIR

Tags: air, code-signing

I've been signing my Adobe AIR applications with a self-generated certificate, but now I'd like something that looks more official. What sort of commercial certificate should I get and from where?

As always, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some more looking, I found an answer in the [AIR docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ff0.html):

**About Certificate formats**

The AIR signing tools accept any keystores accessible through the Java Cryptography Architecture (JCA). This includes file-based keystores such as PKCS12-format files (which typically use a .pfx or .p12 file extension), Java .keystore files, PKCS11 hardware keystores, and the system keystores. The keystore formats that ADT can access depend on the version and configuration of the Java runtime used to run ADT. Accessing some types of keystore, such as PKCS11 hardware tokens, may require the installation and configuration of additional software drivers and JCA plug-ins.

To sign AIR files, you can use most existing code signing certificates or you can obtain a new one issued expressly for signing AIR applications. For example, any of the following types of certificate from VeriSign, Thawte, GlobalSign, or ChosenSecurity can be used:

ChosenSecurity

- TC Publisher ID for Adobe AIR

GlobalSign

- ObjectSign Code Signing Certificate

Thawte

- AIR Developer Certificate
- Apple Developer Certificate
- JavaSoft Developer Certificate
- Microsoft Authenticode Certificate

VeriSign

- Adobe AIR Digital ID
- Microsoft Authenticode Digital ID
- Sun Java Signing Digital ID

Note: The certificate must be created for code signing. You cannot use an SSL or other type of certificate to sign AIR files.

Answer (score 2):

Individuals can now get certificates too: http://blog.digitalbackcountry.com/2009/01/adobe-air-certificates-for-individuals-now-available/